# Creating UArray Int (Complex Double) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, complex-numbers

I am attempting to have a `UArray Int (Complex Double)`. This signature is fine, however when I try to access a specific index using `(!)` I receive an error. Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
test :: UArray Int (Complex Double) -> Complex Double
test arr = arr ! 0
```

and the error I am getting:

```
No instance for (IArray UArray (Complex Double)) arising from a use of `!'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (IArray UArray (Complex Double))
In the expression: arr ! 0
In an equation for `test': test arr = arr ! 0
```

This worked fone for `UArray Int Double` and I am curiouis as to why this does not work for (Complex Double). Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`Data.Array.Unboxed documentation`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-Unboxed.html#t%3aUArray), there seem to be instances of [`IArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-IArray.html#t%3aArray) with `UArray` just for types like `Char`, `Double` or `Int`, not polymorphic. If you need to store values of other types, you should use boxed [`Array`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-IArray.html#t%3aArray).

Comment: Thanks! Another option is to use Vector.Unboxed.